# $scope.$emit not working while $rootScope.$broadcast does

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

Here's my parent controller where I listen for the event

```
app.controller("SectionLayoutController", function($scope) {

  $scope.$on("sectionLayout.doAction", function(e, options) {
    // do some stuff
  });

});
```

And in my child controller I do this

```
$scope.$emit("sectionLayout.doAction", { someOption: "something" });
```

The event should be triggered in the parent controller but it isn't. I did check what the contents of my child controller's scope was (with console.log) right before emitting the event, and the listener for the event does exist in one of its parents.

[image]

Maybe it's because the child controller's scope is not a direct child of the scope where the event is being listened on? This is not really a critical issue because I can just replace the line with

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("sectionLayout.doAction", { someOption: "something" });
```

and it works fine, but I'm still curious as to why $scope.$emit isn't working (it did work at some point, it just stopped randomly).

(Angular version 1.2.16)

Comment: Can you create a plunkr to prove that? If it is not working, then you might want to create an issue to angularjs. I used $scope.$emit and I never encounter this issue. (Using 1.2.18 right now and previously 1.1.X). According to docs, $emit should traverse upwards toward the root scope.

Comment: I'll just update to older revisions until it worked, and try to figure out what changes broke it, and yeah I should update angular

Comment: @hutingung here's the plunkr of the bug in action http://plnkr.co/edit/zgqAPiDbB2LUtwJaeHhN?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be a bug in angular.js, not ui-router (it has already been reported and is scheduled for a fix in version 1.3 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5489). Using ng-transclude inside a directive seems to create a sibling scope for the directive, which makes this kind of hierarchy (with my first plunker example) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V2eV.png.

So yeah, I guess for now i'll be using $rootScope.$broadcast

---

Ok, so from what I've found, this is a bug with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (forgot to mention I was using that, oops).

If the ui-view of a child route is inside a transcluded directive, events will get stuck there. Here's a plunkr of that bug in action http://plnkr.co/edit/zgqAPiDbB2LUtwJaeHhN?p=preview. The Dummy controller uses the sectionLayout directive and the ui-view is transcluded (as you can see in dummy.html).

```
<!-- dummy.html -->
<div section-layout="layout">
  <!-- transcluded stuff -->
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>

<!-- sectionlayout.html -->
<div>
  <p>Section Layout for {{layout.title}}</p>
  <p ng-repeat="r in recieves">{{r.message}}</p>

  <div ng-transclude style="background-color: #EEE;"></div>
</div>
```

---

Here's another plunkr where $scope.$emit does work, and the only difference is that the ui-view is directly inside sectionlayout.html instead of transcluded in the directive http://plnkr.co/edit/mVftwkZrynkF6KanE4zV?p=preview.

```
<!-- dummy.html -->
<div section-layout="layout"></div>

<!-- sectionlayout.html -->
<div>
  <p>Section Layout for {{layout.title}}</p>
  <p ng-repeat="r in recieves">{{r.message}}</p>

  <div ui-view style="background-color: #EEE;"></div>
</div>
```

---

And here's a completely different plunkr where I don't use ui-router, but it's still the same thing. A directive is used in a parent where events are listened, and the child controller is transcluded in the directive. In this one, both $scope.$emit and $rootScope.$broadcast work fine, so it seems to be a bug with transcluded ui-views in ui-router. http://plnkr.co/edit/Iz5YcbMiTzrXQ6bJMskK?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  <p>Parent Controller</p>
  <p ng-repeat="r in recieves">{{r.message}}</p>

  <div my-directive>
    <div ng-controller="ChildController" style="background-color: #EEE;">
      <p>Child Controller</p>
      <button ng-click="tryEmit()">$scope.$emit</button>
      <button ng-click="tryBroadcast()">$rootScope.$broadcast</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll report this bug on their github page

Comment: For example that you build with ui-router, you put listener under the directive but the other one you put under ParentController. If you are testing in directive, you might want to understand about inheritance and isolation of scope. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes . [Quote from docs] In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope. One exception to this rule is a directive that uses scope: { ... } -- this creates an "isolate" scope that does not prototypically inherit.

Comment: I fork your example and added listener at DummyController. Listener at DummyController(parent scope) is working fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/EeE5zfWuaTxR2h5hROP4?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, your fork seems to not be working from my end. Maybe this is a browser issue, I'm using chrome 36. Also the event NEEDS to be in the sectionlayout.

Comment: Also, What you said isn't true, take a look at my 2nd and 3rd plunkr. My second one is exactly the same as my first one, except its <div ui-view></div> is NOT transcluded. My third one has the same structure of the 1st one, except it doesn't use ui-router. Both have isolate scopes and $scope.$emit works, so having my directive not prototypically inherit is not the issue here.

Comment: You need to check console. I log to console not on screen.

Comment: I see, but this still doesn't fix the problem, there is a bug and it's not because of isolate scopes (because my 2nd and 3rd plunkers work WITH isolate scopes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57867/discussion-between-hutingung-and-louis-boux).